# A .DS_Store file is created when an assetpack is downloaded with play asset delivery

Tags: android, google-play-core, android-asset-delivery

In my app, additional assets are delivered to users through `Play Asset Delivery` `on-demand.`

However, we found a case where `.DS_Store` was included in the asset path when downloading the corresponding `AssetPack` to specific users.

ex) `/data/data/com.example.app/files/assetpacks/font_asset/45/45/assets/.DS_Store`

Looking at the working principle of `Play Asset Delivery`, I know that the asset module is uploaded to Google Play as an `.aab` file, and it is downloaded and installed, but I do not know in what path the `.DS_Store` file is added.

can you give me some advice?

Comment: The person who built that specific asset pack, are they working on a Mac? It looks to me like an errant Mac file got accidentally packaged in to the aab.

Comment: @LevM. Yes I am currently working on macOS.
However, I do not understand that this issue occurs only to a few users, not all users.

Comment: All I know is that .DS_Store is a hidden file MacOS tends to create in folders. I got a few of them in projects from coworkers using Macs. According to this: https://buildthis.com/ds_store-files-and-why-you-should-know-about-them/ it is only created if you look in the folder with the Finder app. Maybe in your build process some folders are created automatically, and so the file is not present there while packaging, but if you manually inspect some other folders, that is what's adding the file...

Comment: @LevM. Basically, it seems like i have to deal with .DS_Store not being packaged like you said. Thanks for your help.